# Expected number of draws to draw a unique item given outcome probability distribution with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a mystery box with multiple outcomes, if the outcome of concern has a probability of being drawn with 15%, what is the expected number of draws to draw this outcome?

Can we assign a dollar value to this outcome if each draw costs $3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple geometric distribution. Let $X$ be the number of trials until the first success. Then

$$P(X = k) = (1 - .15)^{k-1}\times .15$$

The expected value can be shown to be $\frac{1}{.15} = 6 \frac{2}{3}$, so you can expect about six draws to get the outcome of concern. If each draw costs three dollars, then with a prize of twenty dollars you'll break even on average.